# WPF Bind to Observable Collection within XAML declared class instance

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have got an instance of a class defined in my **App.xaml**, so this instance is accessible from anywhere in the application.

**The Class**

```
using Common;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace PhotoManagement
{
    public class LoggedUsers : NotifyUIBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Logged> Logged = new ObservableCollection<Logged>();
        public void Add(Logged user)
        {
            Logged.Add(user);
            UpdateView(); //Check the List for users
            RaisePropertyChanged("Logged"); //Notify View binding there is a change
        }

        //Check if there is a user logged in
        public void UpdateView()
        {
            if (Logged.Count < 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No one logged in!");
                //No user is logged in, navigate to login view
                //views[0].NavigateExecute(); Does not work, as views object is out of scope
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Someone is logged in!");
                //User is logged in, navigate to home view
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see below, I have setup an instance of the class in my XAML and given is a Key:

```
<Application x:Class="PhotoManagement.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PhotoManagement"
             StartupUri="/Views/Main/MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:LoggedUsers x:Key="LoggedUsers" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I have checked that items are being added to the list, as when the **Add()** method is called, it also runs the **UpdateView()** method which shows me that there is a value.

However i'm struggling to display Items in a ListView, or the ListView isn't being notified of the update, however it should be!

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Logged, Source={StaticResource LoggedUsers}}" Width="100" Height="100">
    <ListViewItem>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
    </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

The above ListView remains empty even when I add an item to the ListView.

This is the **Logged** class also:

```
namespace PhotoManagement
{
    public class Logged
    {
        public string ClearPassword { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public long UID { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        //Display basic statistics 
        public int ThisDayImageCount { get; set; }
        public int ThisDaySaleCount { get; set; }

        public Logged()
        {
            //Update the stats when instigated
            UpdateStats();
        }

        //Update the stats
        public void UpdateStats()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with the code.

- `Logged` should be a property, not a field. You can't bind to fields.

  ```
  public ObservableCollection<Logged> Logged { get; set; }
  ```

  Also add a constructor to `LoggedUsers` to initialize the property (or use C# 6's auto-property initializers):

  ```
  public LoggedUsers()
  {
      Logged = new ObservableCollection<Logged>();
  }
  ```
- The XAML should look like this:

  ```
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Logged, Source={StaticResource LoggedUsers}}" Width="100" Height="100">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate DataType="local:Logged">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
          </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
  ```
- I don't think you need `RaisePropertyChanged("Logged");`. `ObservableCollection` notifies about the change of its content.

After these modification, now if you do this somewhere in your application:

```
var loggedUsers = FindResource("LoggedUsers") as LoggedUsers;

if (loggedUsers != null)
{
    loggedUsers.Add(new Logged()
    {
        FirstName = "John"
    });
}
```

You will get the update.

[image: result]

Comment: Getting the following error on the Text Binding: `Additional information: 'Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' threw an exception.' Line number '54' and line position '32'.`

Comment: How does your XAML look like now? You did remove the `<ListViewItem><TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" /></ListViewItem>` and only have what I have in the answer, right? I think you left in that part from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Few things:

1.You dont need to call RaisePropertyChanged for  `ObservableCollection<Logged> Logged`

```
    public void Add(Logged user)
    {
        Logged.Add(user);
        UpdateView(); //Check the List for users
        //You dont need this RaisedPropertyChanged
        RaisePropertyChanged("Logged"); //Notify View binding there is a change
    }
```

2.Logged should be a property - `ObservableCollection<Logged> Logged {get; private set;}` then use its constructor to initialize it

```
public LoggedUsers
{
 Logged = new ObservableCollection<Logged>();
}
```

3.Implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface for `public class Logged`, you will need it and if you are going to update the values outside their constructor.

```
public string ClearPassword { get; set; }
```

should be

```
private string _clearPassword
publuc string ClearPassword
{
  get { return _clearPassword;}
  set
 { 
   _clearPassword = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged("ClearPassword");
  }
}
```

Also do it for the rest of the properties.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I took it all on board, the other answer fixed the binding issues however.